# question about the proof of  the positive mass theorem

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, dg.differential-geometry

Hello. I'm reading the paper "Proof of the positive mass theorem II" by Schoen and Yau. I have some questions.

**Question 1**

In page 236, they used the Simons' identity
$$
\begin{aligned}
\Delta h_{ij} = & \bar{D}_{i} \bar{D}_{j} H+ D_{k} R_{4ijk} + D_{j} R_{4kik} - |A|^2 h_{ij} + H h_{im} h_{mj} \\ 
                & -2 h_{mk} R_{mikj} - h_{im} R_{mkkj} - H R_{4ij4} - R_{4k4k} h_{ij} + R_{mkik} h_{mj}
\end{aligned}                  
$$
and the falloff conditions (1.1) (that is, $|g_{ij}-\delta_{ij}|+r|\partial g_{ij}|+r|\partial g_{ij}|+r^2|\partial\partial g_{ij}|\leq c$) 
to obtain the following inequality (2.13) (see P 237):
$$ \frac{1}{2} \Delta |A|^2 \geq |\bar {D} h|^2 - |A|^4 - |H||A|^3 + h_{ij} \bar {D}_{i} \bar {D}_{j} H - c_{2} (|A|^2 + 2) $$

Note that the derivatives of the Riemannian tensors appear in the Simons' identity, while the falloff conditions do not say anything on the third derivatives of the metric. My first question is how do they control the terms $D_{i} R_{4ijk} + D_{j} R_{4kik}$ ?

**Question 2**

They used the standard continuity method to solve the auxiliary Jang's equation
$H(f)-sP(f)=tf$
in Lemma 3. In this proof, they constructed the operator from $B^{2, \beta}\times R$ to $B^{0, \beta}\times R$
defined by
$T(f,s) = (H(f)-tf-sP(f),s)$.
Here, $f$ belongs to $B^{2, \beta}$ or $B^{0, \beta}$ if the following norms are finite respectively.
$$||f||_{2,\beta}= \sup_{N} ( \tau ^{\beta}(x)|f(x)|+\tau ^{1+\beta}(x)|Df(x)|+\tau ^{2+\beta}(x)|DDf(x)|+\tau ^{2+2\beta}(x)||DDf(x)||_{\beta,x});$$
$$||f||_{0,\beta}= \sup_{N} ( \tau ^{2+\beta}(x)|f(x)|+\tau ^{2+2\beta}(x)||f(x)||_{\beta,x})$$
These weighted Holder norms are convenient to write down the Schauder estimates.
If $T$ is well defined, it implies $f \in  B^{0, \beta}$ and hence $ B^{2, \beta} \subseteq B^{0, \beta}$. But this is impossible. What's wrong?

**Question 3**

In the proof of proposition 4, I can not understand why local parametric estimates immediately implies that a sequence of graphs converges to a properly embedded limiting submanifold?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you should post 3 separate question? And state all the equations and inequalities explicitly, instead of citing page and equation numbers from the paper?

Comment: Totally agree with @Deane, though I do think the question is good in principle.

Comment: I think I might be able to answer question 1, but I don't really want to download the paper and look everything up.

Comment: Also, please define your notation. For example, what is $B^{2,\beta}$?

Comment: excuse me, if I finish typying, how can I make a preview?

Comment: Thanks for rewriting Questions 1 and 2, but Question 3 still requires more details to understand.

Comment: Question 1: Does the proof of the inequality really use the falloff conditions? Have you tried to work through the proof yourself?

Comment: @Deane, Question 3 do need more details and I will specify it latter. I apologize for the indeterminacy in Q3. Actually I want to focus on Q1 and 2  first, for they pullze me much more. 
It seems that no terms in the Simon's identity are of favorable signs,  so I think it needs the falloff conditions.

Comment: Perhaps you should also read Lohkamp's paper on Positive Mass Theorem 
http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0608795.pdf